# Did Kazuki get a new body?

Tags: grisaia

In the Grisaia no Rakuen, it is revealed at the end of episode 5 that,

> Kasuki is still alive as part of the Thanatos system.

Furthermore in episode 8,

> She gets a body.
>  [image]

Questions are:

- Is Kazuki's body in episode 8 her original body at the time of her "death" preserved through the years? Or was it newly grown in a laboratory?
- Is there any hard evidence suggesting either?

Kazuki's body doesn't seem to have aged though it may be difficult to tell. Either way, that doesn't give any new information.

- A cryopreserved body would retain the original age.
- Likewise a body in a vegetative state would continue to age at the normal rate.
- A newly grown body can be given an arbitrary look and age.

Comment: I'm sure Kazuki herself explains this in one of earlier Rakuen episodes. She survived, found by Ichigaya and was used as part of Thanatos without her consent.

Comment: Right, that explains why she's alive in the Thanatos system in the first place. But I don't recall seeing anything about what they did to her body and whether or not it's the same one she "gets back" in episode 8.

Comment: Patience, Mysticial. There are at least 5 more episodes to go. The fact they did not expose that does not means it will remain in the dark. Remember that Japanese storytelling is less linear then western(ref needed). They just love flashbacks and late exposition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

begin TL;DR:

> No.

end TL;DR.

---

When Kazuki was sold to make the Thanatos system, the system creators were faced with a dilemma:

> how to keep the brain alive.

Their original intent was to

> cut off the brain and hook the organ directly to the machinery

But then they would have to deal with a "little" problem:

> they would need to supply nutrients, oxygen, antibodies, leukocytes, and all sorts of stuff to the brain.

That would require additional machinery/technology, but then they realized that

> a human body already does all that, you just have to shove food and oxygen through the mouth and nose.

So they decided to ditch their original plan and

> just hook Kazuki's brain indirectly to the machinery, and keep the body intact in life support fluid (think of Evangelion's LCL).

---

About Kazuki's body not aging, she was 12/13 years old when the [accident happened](http://grisaia.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Takizono_Academy_Minibus_Accident).

> Her body was not frozen. It was kept in a vegetative-comatose-ish state. In the visual novels, she is very debilitated when rescued by JB, and had to be carried out of Ichigaya by the German blonde.

Also a spoiler of future episodes, so don't read below:

> the hook in her hand (the one she injuried in the bus crash) is fake. Her arm/hand is fine and she thinks she is making a great pun, but Kazuki is running for **worst sense of humor in a VN/anime character ever.** Who gave her that grappling hand in the suspended animation chamber, it is stuff for another question.

[According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puberty#Timing_of_the_onset_of_puberty), females end puberty earlier than males, and reach an adult body earlier too:

> Maximal adult height is achieved at an average age of 15 years for an average girl and 18 years for an average boy.

So, we can assume Kazuki grew around two more year's worth since the accident. Her body frame was always petite and she was precocious in several aspects, why not puberty? She was around the same size as Amane during the accident, so maybe her growth spurt had already happened by then.

And to boot:

> She was sexually active since a very tender age. Her favorite food is Yuuji (eden ep.6), nuff said.

Probably that caused her puberty to have an early onset.